# Using GWT source code in Android

Tags: android, gwt, guice, gwt-gin

I have a web app based on GWT. I use the same code base to target desktop as well as mobile platforms. I am using Model-View-Presenter and Dependency Injection based on GIN to achieve the goal of being cross platform compatible. However for better performance and native look-and-feel on Android, I would like to write to a fully native app. I want start by migrating the same GWT Java code to a new Android project and replace just the View implementations with native views that make use of native widgets. Has anybody tried this ? Besides the obvious issues like bloated code and extra memory consumption due to DI are there any other major issues?

Answer (score 1):

This can be done. In fact, several apps have done it. Google inbox which is currently in beta but is supposed to replace gmail one day uses gwt to share 70% if it's code between android and javaScript. I plan to put my app on android too. Also, many tools have support for that. gin, gwt sync proxy and others all have support for android. Also, the putnami-gradle-plugin is a plugin for gradle that might support this in the future. One of the biggest issues I'm having is that there are very few libraries work on gwt and android. I'm interested in using mvp4g in an android app so I created this issue: https://code.google.com/p/mvp4g/issues/detail?id=133